# android getViewById() NullPointerException

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception, findviewbyid

I'm trying to make my app changes its layout when user rotate the screen.
When i launch the app while the screen of virtual machines is in portrait position.
The app is ok when launch but when I rotate the screen to landscape, the app will stops and the logCat shows a nullPointerException at line 40

line 39 `btn=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btn);`

line 40 `btn.setOnClickListener(btnListener);`

I think the findViewById() method is returning null, but i dont know why.
Also, if i launch the app while screen in landscape position, the same error occured.

**SOLVED: the problem might be the arrangement of nested if, add braces for every if and else-if do solve this problem**

Here are the codes:

MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.test;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.AlertDialog.Builder;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {


    SharedPreferences preference;
    Button btn;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        preference = getSharedPreferences("preferences", MODE_PRIVATE);
        if(getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == 1)
            if(preference.getInt("THE_CHECKED", 0) == 0)
                setContentView(R.layout.portrait_black);
            else if(preference.getInt("THE_CHECKED", 0) == 1)
                setContentView(R.layout.portrait_white);
        else if(getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == 2)
            if(preference.getInt("THE_CHECKED", 0) == 0)
                setContentView(R.layout.landscape_black);
            else if(preference.getInt("THE_CHECKED", 0) == 1)
                setContentView(R.layout.landscape_white);

        btn=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btn);
        btn.setOnClickListener(btnListener);
    }

    private Button.OnClickListener btnListener = new Button.OnClickListener()
    {
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            Toast toast1 = Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "HI", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            toast1.show();
        }
    };

    private DialogInterface.OnClickListener theDialogListener = new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
    {
    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which)
    {
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preference.edit();
        switch(which)
        {
            case 0: //Black
                editor.putInt("THE_CHECKED", 0);
                break;
            case 1: //White
                editor.putInt("THE_CHECKED", 1);
                break;
        }
        editor.commit();
        ((Dialog)dialog).dismiss();
        onCreate(new Bundle());
    }
    };
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)
    {
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preference.edit();
        switch (item.getItemId())
        {
            case R.id.theme:
                Builder theDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
                theDialog.setTitle("Theme");
                theDialog.setSingleChoiceItems(R.array.theme_menu, preference.getInt("THE_CHECKED", 0), theDialogListener);
                theDialog.show();
                break;
        }
        editor.commit();
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        onCreate(new Bundle());
    }

}
```

Layouts

portrait_white.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/LinearLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#FFFFFF"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="portrait"
            android:textSize="30sp"
            android:textColor="#000000" />
</LinearLayout>
```

portrait_black.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/LinearLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#000000"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="portrait"
            android:textSize="30sp"
            android:textColor="#000000" />
</LinearLayout>
```

landscape_white.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/LinearLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#FFFFFF"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="landscape"
            android:textSize="30sp"
            android:textColor="#000000" />
</LinearLayout>
```

landscape_black.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/LinearLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#000000"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="landscape"
            android:textSize="30sp"
            android:textColor="#000000" />
</LinearLayout>
```

LogCat(when i launch the app while screen is in landscape position)

```
02-21 01:26:53.895: D/AndroidRuntime(1836): Shutting down VM
02-21 01:26:53.925: W/dalvikvm(1836): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41465700)
02-21 01:26:53.935: E/AndroidRuntime(1836): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-21 01:26:53.935: E/AndroidRuntime(1836): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.test/com.example.test.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
02-21 01:26:53.935: E/AndroidRuntime(1836):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2211)
02-21 01:26:53.935: E/AndroidRuntime(1836):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261)
02-21 01:26:53.935: E/AndroidRuntime(1836):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
02-21 01:26:53.935: E/AndroidRuntime(1836):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)
02-21 01:26:53.935: E/AndroidRuntime(1836):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
02-21 01:26:53.935: E/AndroidRuntime(1836):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
02-21 01:26:53.935: E/AndroidRuntime(1836):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
02-21 01:26:53.935: E/AndroidRuntime(1836):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-21 01:26:53.935: E/AndroidRuntime(1836):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
02-21 01:26:53.935: E/AndroidRuntime(1836):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
02-21 01:26:53.935: E/AndroidRuntime(1836):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
02-21 01:26:53.935: E/AndroidRuntime(1836):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-21 01:26:53.935: E/AndroidRuntime(1836): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
02-21 01:26:53.935: E/AndroidRuntime(1836):     at com.example.test.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:40)
02-21 01:26:53.935: E/AndroidRuntime(1836):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5133)
02-21 01:26:53.935: E/AndroidRuntime(1836):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
02-21 01:26:53.935: E/AndroidRuntime(1836):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2175)
02-21 01:26:53.935: E/AndroidRuntime(1836):     ... 11 more
```

Thanks.

Comment: check Is there any if else condition true

Comment: I think setContentView() is not called, while rotation. Try to set a default contentView after if else

Comment: Setup breakpoints and see if any of the setContentViews are actually being called! Your If Else might be going wrong

Comment: you can use same xml file names for portrait and landscape mode in two folders layout-land and layout-port

Comment: you have written wrong if else statements

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't have `setContentView()` in your `Activity`, hence, there's actually no `View` referenced to your activity and no views to find using `findViewById()` method, make sure the `setContentView()` was actually called...

Regards!

Comment: i got four different 
setContentView() arguments in four situation
1. portrait  -- black
2. portrait -- white
3. landscape -- black
4. landscape -- white
i cant think of a situation which none was called...

Comment: at the end of all your if-else, add an else, and set one of the setContentViews, all your validations are failing...

Answer (score 1):

Use it this way. You have written nested if else and the second condition will never be executed in landscape mode i.e.  **orientation==2**

```
  package com.example.test;

    import android.os.Bundle;
     import android.app.Activity;
          import android.app.AlertDialog;
     import android.app.AlertDialog.Builder;
      import android.app.Dialog;
      import android.content.DialogInterface;
     import android.content.SharedPreferences;
     import android.content.res.Configuration;
    import android.view.Menu;
   import android.view.MenuItem;
     import android.view.View;
     import android.widget.Button;
     import android.widget.Toast;


   public class MainActivity extends Activity {


SharedPreferences preference;
Button btn;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    preference = getSharedPreferences("preferences", MODE_PRIVATE);
             if(getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == 1)
        {
        if(preference.getInt("THE_CHECKED", 0) == 0)
            setContentView(R.layout.portrait_black);
        else if(preference.getInt("THE_CHECKED", 0) == 1)
            setContentView(R.layout.portrait_white);
      }
    else if(getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == 2)
        if(preference.getInt("THE_CHECKED", 0) == 0)
            setContentView(R.layout.landscape_black);
        else if(preference.getInt("THE_CHECKED", 0) == 1)
            setContentView(R.layout.landscape_white);

    btn=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btn);
    btn.setOnClickListener(btnListener);
}

private Button.OnClickListener btnListener = new Button.OnClickListener()
{
    public void onClick(View v)
    {
        Toast toast1 = Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "HI", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        toast1.show();
    }
};

private DialogInterface.OnClickListener theDialogListener = new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
{
@Override
public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which)
{
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preference.edit();
    switch(which)
    {
        case 0: //Black
            editor.putInt("THE_CHECKED", 0);
            break;
        case 1: //White
            editor.putInt("THE_CHECKED", 1);
            break;
    }
    editor.commit();
    ((Dialog)dialog).dismiss();
    onCreate(new Bundle());
}
};
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)
{
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preference.edit();
    switch (item.getItemId())
    {
        case R.id.theme:
            Builder theDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            theDialog.setTitle("Theme");
            theDialog.setSingleChoiceItems(R.array.theme_menu, preference.getInt("THE_CHECKED", 0), theDialogListener);
            theDialog.show();
            break;
    }
    editor.commit();
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    onCreate(new Bundle());
}

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you print the getResources().getConfiguration().orientation, I think it may be others values than 1 and 2
Infact, we have 4 value of getResources().getConfiguration().orientation: Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT = 1, Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE =2, Configuration.ORIENTATION_SQUARE =3, Configuration.ORIENTATION_UNDEFINED =0